# Can't complete an application for Google for Non Profits

Tags: google, google-workspace

I'm working with a client who is leaving their less-than-adequate shared hosting ISP for something more suitable for their needs.  Part of that something involves getting them off shared-ISP-email and over to Google for Non Profits since they are a 501c3.

The problem is that when we go to create the Google for Non Profits account, Google responds that the someone else has already started the process.  No one has any idea who that person would be.  When we attempt to notify that person for admin access via the Google Signup Page, no response is forthcoming. We are concerned that a do-gooder volunteer or staff member started a process who knows when and forgot about it/closed the email address used to start it so we are in perpetual limbo. Attempts to set up a separate foundation to trick Google into granting access for that also don't work.

tl;dr How do we get Google to reset the domain so that we can restart the non-profit application so the charity can get services without paying for it?

Comment: I am not sure you can. I think I would be recommending a dedicated server and IP address with a clean history so that e-mail can be sent. As part of that, the host must remove any host234.example.com style domain name so that the a PTR record could be properly registered and not conflicted with. These are normal requests for dedicated servers and IP addresses so do not take "No." for an answer. This scenario does not have to cost too much. It could be a simple blade server. Just make sure you use a quality host company. Otherwise, I have no ideas for you. Sorry. I wish I did.

Comment: This shouldn't have anything to do with PTR's and IP addresses.  You create a Google account (or use an existing one) and then apply for non-profit status for the domain. When I try it for this client, Google says it's been done already and we get into a circular loop since whoever did the application prior isn't responding to our attempts to ping them.

Comment: I realize that. I am suggesting an alternative where the organization would have better control. I am an ex web host so I kinda know the business though it has changed lately. I am saying if you are having trouble going the Google route, then perhaps a quality host can help and still be affordable. I used to run a list-server and could always route e-mails through it for safe bulk e-mail contact. It was transparent to the organization and it's e-mail recipients and handled hundreds of thousands of e-mail each day. I hosted charities, organizations, churches, and so on so it was affordable.

Comment: Ah. I'm trying to move them and get rid of th...erm...transition them to independence.

Comment: I understand. Another thought depending upon how much they want to take on is to run their own in-house server. It does not have to be hard and with a small maintenance contract, this is possible. I would warn that a commercial DSL connection would be preferred so that the e-mail options remain open. You can use Webmin or Virtualmin and they can do much of the work themselves in creating users, files space, updating their website, etc. They really do not have to be too tech savvy. If Catholic Nuns can do it... well... I'd rather be telling you how to solve your problem, I wish I could.

Comment: Have you tried some of the Google forums?? Employees troll these things and sometimes they can intervene on your behalf. It sure would be nice if Google did have some level of support even if you are just filling out a form and they e-mail you back and it takes a while. Perhaps a button during the account creation process. This would be good for business you would think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that if you dig deep enough, there is a human support person that can be called.  You will need to provide them with all sorts of documentation and identification to prove you are indeed able to make decisions on behalf of the organization.  Then, and only then, will Google reset the application status and allow you to re-apply for GAFNPs.